Having difficulty is using the wait time in the selenium + Jmeter where am trying to extract the userid from the local storage of the application
Can any one show how to extract the local storage value in the jmeter.
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium, org.openqa.selenium.support.ui);
var jmeterVariables = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables();

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
WDS.browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WDS.log.info("Sample started");

try {
    WDS.browser.get(jmeterVariables.get('url'));

    var userName = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//input[@id='username']"));
    userName.sendKeys(jmeterVariables.get('userName'));

    var password = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//input[@id='password']"));
    password.sendKeys(jmeterVariables.get('Password'));

    var loginButton = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//button[@type='submit' and contains(@class, 'login-button')]"));
    loginButton.click();

    WDS.browser.get(jmeterVariables.get('url1'));

    WDS.log.info("User logged in successfully");

    // Wait for the page to load for 30-40 seconds
    var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 40); // Adjust the timeout as needed
    var element = wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath("//some/xpath")));
    // Perform actions with the element after it's located
    // element.click(); // Example action after element is located

    // Extract refresh token from local storage
    var tokenStorageValue;
    allStorage();
    var value = JSON.parse(tokenStorageValue);
    jmeterVariables.put('refresh_Token', value.secret);

    WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();

} catch (e) {
    WDS.log.error("Error occurred: " + e);
} finally {
    // Ensure to quit the browser after execution
    WDS.browser.quit();
}

function allStorage() {
    for (var key = 0; key <= WDS.browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.length"); key++) {
        var keyName = WDS.browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.key(" + key + ")");
        if (keyName.indexOf('refreshtoken') > 0) {
            tokenStorageValue = WDS.browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage.getItem('" + keyName + "')");
            break;
        }
    }
}

Here am facing the issue in the jmeter log as
2024-07-13 01:40:03,098 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Error occurred: TypeError: Can not create new object with constructor org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures.
Now While am trying to ask the browser to wait for 40 seconds to extract the user id from the local storage. I see the above error in the log.

As of WebDriverWait JavaDoc 2nd parameter is Duration and you're passing an Integer there and that's why your code fails.
You need to change this line:
var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 40);

to this one:
 var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(40));

and at least this error will go away.
Also regarding using JavaScript - it's not the best idea because:

It's some form of a performance anti-pattern, since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Element and Groovy language for scripting. See Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For? article for more details
JavaScript runtime has been removed from Java 15 so you will have problems with running your script on newer Java versions


so do you suggest me to switch to groovy and check

I suggest you to use correct function
